# Amazon route 53 first time

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm wondering if I set up my  Amazon Route 53 records correctly to run on my Amazon EC2 instance which has an elastic IP, django webapp running on nginx and gunicorn:

It is my first time so I would love to hear if this setup is correct (especially is A record ok for www.mysite.com  as my mysite.com)

Here it is:

[image: My amazon Route 53 screenshot]

It currently works, both `www.mysite.com` and `mysite.com` points to my nginx 'welcome to nginx' blank page.

I will be grateful for any feedback if this is set up correct (especially TTL and www. type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using A records for both is fine (you can't use a CNAME for mysite.com anyway). You could increase the TTL though (to 1h or 1d) -- it doesn't need to be low since it's pointing at an elastic IP, and the elastic IP allows you to change the target. The only reason to keep the TTL low is if you might need to point the domain at another EC2 region or a non-EC2 server.